# How can Ihave a Map <String,integer> in javaScript

Tags: javascript, mapping

I am new JavaScript how can I create a map with String,Integer structure, and also how to iterate it and I tried like this`

```
var map = {};
var tempVlues = text.split(" ");
for(var i=0;i<tempVlues.length;i++){
    var v = tempVlues[i];
    if(v.length > 1)
        {
        if(map[v]==='undefined')
            map[v]=1;
        alert(map[v]);//getting undefined
        }else{
            map[v] = map[v]+1;
        }
}
```

Comment: You're missing `typeof` in `if( typeof map[v] === 'undefined')` - as it is you're checking if the value of `map[v]` is literally the string `'undefined'`

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you had formatted the code you would have figured it yourself.

```
var tempValues = "abcd efgh    ".split(" "),
    map = {};
for (var i = 0; i < tempValues.length; i++) {
    var v = tempValues[i];
    if (v.length > 1) {
        if (map[v] === undefined) {
            map[v] = 1;
        } else {
            map[v] = map[v] + 1;
        }
    }
}
console.log(map);
# { abcd: 1, efgh: 1 }
```

If the value is not found, you will get `undefined` (not a string).

This can be shortened further, like this

```
if (v.length > 1) {
    map[v] = map.hasOwnProperty(v) ? map[v] + 1 : 1
}
```

`map.hasOwnProperty(v)` checks of the property `v` exists in `map`. If it does, we add 1 to the value which is already in `map[v]` otherwise we assign 1.